# Having 2 javascript in one html

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have 2 javascript file running on one single HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/enhancements.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/part2-payment.js"></script>
```

Both of these script will be loaded in my payment.html page

But it is conflicting because it is loading the bottom one rather than the top one.

Script 1 - part2-payment.js

```
/**
* Author: Kelvin Chong Choon Siong
* Target: payment.html
* Purpose: Validate and carry forward information to Payment.html
* Created: 14 Apr 2017
* Last updated: 17-04-17
*/
"use strict";

function destroyAll(){
    sessionStorage.clear();
    window.location = "index.html";
}

function calcCost(bikeType, quantity){
    var result = "";
    if (bikeType == "Road Bicycle (City Bike) $300") {
        result = (300) * quantity;
    }
    if (bikeType == "Cyclocross Bicycle $330") {
        result = (330) * quantity;
    }
    if (bikeType == "Touring  Bicycle $310") {
        result = (310) * quantity;
    }
    if (bikeType == "Track/Fixed-Gear Bicycle $380") {
        result = (380) * quantity;
    }
    if (bikeType == "Mountain Bicycle $340") {
        result = (340) * quantity;
    }
    if (bikeType == "BMX  Bicycle $380") {
        result = (380) * quantity;
    }
    if (bikeType == "Folding  Bicycle $450") {
        result = (450) * quantity;
    }
    if (bikeType == "Tandem  Bicycle $600") {
        result = (600) * quantity;
    }
    return result;
}

function getBooking(){
    if(sessionStorage.fname != undefined){    //if sessionStorage for username is not empty
        //confirmation text
        document.getElementById("fname").textContent = sessionStorage.fname + " " + sessionStorage.lname;
        document.getElementById('address').textContent = sessionStorage.address + ", " + sessionStorage.suburb + ", " + sessionStorage.state + ", " + sessionStorage.postcode;
        document.getElementById('emailadd').textContent = sessionStorage.emailadd;
        document.getElementById('phonenumber').textContent = sessionStorage.pnumber;
        document.getElementById('features').textContent = sessionStorage.extra;
        document.getElementById('comments').textContent = sessionStorage.comments;
        document.getElementById('type_bike').textContent = sessionStorage.bikeType;
        document.getElementById('quantity1').textContent = sessionStorage.quantity;
        document.getElementById('sizez').textContent = sessionStorage.size;
        document.getElementById('cost').textContent = ("AU$ " + calcCost(sessionStorage.bikeType, sessionStorage.quantity));
        //fill hidden fields
        document.getElementById("firstname").value = sessionStorage.fname;
        document.getElementById("lastname").value = sessionStorage.lname;
        document.getElementById("emailAddress").value = sessionStorage.emailadd;
        document.getElementById("homeAddress").value = sessionStorage.address;
        document.getElementById("suburbs").value = sessionStorage.suburb;
        document.getElementById("states").value = sessionStorage.state;
        document.getElementById("postcode").value = sessionStorage.postcode;
        document.getElementById("radioButtons").value = sessionStorage.radiobutton;
        document.getElementById("pnumber").value = sessionStorage.pnumber;
        document.getElementById("type_bike[]").value = sessionStorage.bikeType;
        document.getElementById("quantity[]").value = sessionStorage.quantity;
        document.getElementById("size[]").value = sessionStorage.size;
        document.getElementById("costFinal").value = calcCost(sessionStorage.bikeType, sessionStorage.quantity)
        document.getElementById("extraFeature").value = sessionStorage.extra;
        document.getElementById("comment").value = sessionStorage.comments;
    }
}

function cardExpiry(){
    var errMsg = "";
    var getExpiryDate = document.getElementById("expirydate").value;
    var getMonth = String(getExpiryDate).charAt(0) + String(getExpiryDate).charAt(1);
    var getYear = String(getExpiryDate).charAt(3) + String(getExpiryDate).charAt(4); 
    var dateNow = new Date ();
    var expiryInput = new Date();
    expiryInput.setFullYear('20' + getYear, getMonth-1, 1);

    if (expiryInput < dateNow){
        errMsg = "Your expiration date is before current date. Please change it.\n"
    }
    return errMsg;
}

function cardValidation() {
    /*Visa cards have 16 digits and start with a 4
    MasterCard have 16 digits and start with digits 51 through to 55
    American Express has 15 digits and starts with 34 or 37.*/
    var errMsg = "";
    var cardNumber = document.getElementById('cardnum').value;
    var cardType = document.getElementById('cardType').value;
    var number0 = String(cardNumber).charAt(0);
    var number1 = String(cardNumber).charAt(1);
    switch (cardType) {
        case "Visa":
        if ((number0 !== "4") || (cardNumber.length !== 16)) {
            errMsg = "Visa cards have 16 digits and start with a 4.\n";
        }
        break;
        case "Mastercard":
        if (((number0) !== "5") || ((number1) !== "1" && ((number1) !== "2") && ((number1) !== "3") && ((number1) !== "4") && ((number1) !== "5") ) || (cardNumber.length !== 16)) {
            errMsg = "MasterCard have 16 digits and start with digits 51 through to 55.\n";
        }
        break;
        case "Amex":
        if (((number0) !== "3") || ((number1) !== "4" && ((number1) !== "7")) || (cardNumber.length !== 15))  {
            errMsg = "Amex cards have 15 digits and start with a 34 or 37.\n";
        }
        break;
        default:
            errMsg = "Please write your correct card number.\n";
    }
    return errMsg;
}

function cvvValidation(){
    var errMsg = "";
    var cardType = document.getElementById('cardType').value;
    var cvvcheck = document.getElementById('CVV').value;
    //3 digits, for Visa and Mastercard, 4 digits for American Express.
    switch (cardType) {
        case "Visa":
        if (cvvcheck.length !== 3) {
            errMsg = "Visa cards have a CVV of 3 digits.\n";
        }
        break;
        case "Mastercard":
        if (cvvcheck.length !== 3) {
            errMsg = "MasterCards have a CVV of 3 digits.\n";
        }
        break;
        case "Amex":
        if (cvvcheck.length !== 4)  {
            errMsg = "Amex cards have a CVV of 4 digits..\n";
        }
        break;
        default:
            errMsg = "Please write your correct card CVV.\n";
    }
    return errMsg;
}


function validate() {
    var errMsg = "";
    var result = true;


    var checkCard = cardValidation();
    if (checkCard !== "") {
        errMsg = errMsg + checkCard;
        result = false ;
    }

    var checkCVV = cvvValidation();
        if (checkCVV !== "") {
        errMsg = errMsg + checkCVV;
        result = false ;
    }

    var checkExpiry = cardExpiry();
    if (checkExpiry !== ""){
        errMsg = errMsg + checkExpiry;
        result = false;
    }

    if (errMsg != "") {
        alert(errMsg);
    }

    return result;
}

function init() {
    getBooking();
    var regForm = document.getElementById("form2");
    regForm.onsubmit= validate;
    var destroyEverything = document.getElementById('cancelout');
    destroyEverything.onclick = destroyAll;
}

window.onload = init;
```

So this is Script 2 now

```
Script 2 - enhancements.js
"use strict";

function writeNewMessage(){
    var sMessage = document.getElementById('spanny');
    sMessage.textContent = "this is a test";
}

function init2() {
    var labelTest = document.getElementById("booking_form");
    labelTest.onclick = writeNewMessage;
}

window.onload = init2;
```

I can't figure out how to load both in at the same time.

A few restrictions that I have (because most of the solutions provided on the net I can't use)

```
body onload
No Inline javascript
No jQuery
```

So I was wondering if there is another one to make both work?

Comment: *"but obviously it is conflicting"* - no, that's far from obvious without seeing what those scripts do.

Comment: The HTML you've posted should be working, if it's not then it's likely something elsewhere that's causing it.

Comment: I'll post up the script as well

Comment: they should be loaded and executed in your desired order

Comment: What do you mean by loading at same time?

Comment: I've posted up the script. As you can see, the enhancement is just beginning for now, but it does not contain any similar function name. 

@JonesVinothJoseph I meant like they would work both at the same time, which is not happening now

Comment: Which part do you say is conflicting?

Comment: Well that's the issue, if I put them both, none of the script works. by disabling one, the other works.

Comment: Any errors in the console…?

Comment: window.onload = init2; ...

Comment: @deceze no there is no error from the console. All of them are code 200 OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out by using

```
window.onload = function() {
init();
init2();
};
```

doing this on either one of the js script would work.
All good. On n'est jamais mieux servi que par soi-meme.

Answer (score 1):

Your onloads are overwriting each other:

```
window.onload = init2;//will override window.onload=init;
```

So do:

```
window.addEventListener("load",init2);
```

Same for all the other *clicks, etc.*

Comment: I tried doing the following:

`function init2() {
 var labelTest = document.getElementById("booking_form");

 labelTest.addEventListener("onclick", writeNewMessage);
 }

window.addEventListener("onload", init2);`

but it still is not working, Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @KelvinChong add *console.log("test")* everywhere and see wich parts are not working...

Comment: I'm a bit new to this, but how do I view this log once I've added them?

Comment: yeah there is no error in the console. All loaded with code 200 OK

Comment: @KelvinChong looks like you have to learn far more. Try *how to debug JS code* in google

Comment: Well that's why I'm here asking for help. because I'm new to these..Nevermind, I'll try to figure it out myself.